# How, or where, is this object being initialized?

Tags: php, magento

```
public function getItemsCollection($useCache = true)
  {
      if (is_null($this->_items)) {
          $this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection();
          $this->_items->setQuote($this);
      }
      return $this->_items;
  }
```

In this scope how can I find what is initializing _items? It's not a Magento object that I've come accross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -lir '$this->_items = ' ~/MyProject
```

Comment: Unix platforms... they're just one big IDE

Comment: Not-that-bad answer, but in Magento there are at least three different ways to initialize such a variable, which is accessible via different setter functions…